# Do Owlin have feet or talons?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, strixhaven

I do not currently own the Strixhaven book and one of the players in my new group is playing an Owlin (I am not DMing this one.)

From the description I found online, the Owlin have hands and feet like a humanoid.  Yet every picture I have seen of them shows them with bird talon feet.  Is there an official ruling on this?

A little background, this question came up when we were discussing the Owlin Rogue character swooping between trees while firing at enemies. She wants to land in the trees and use her Cunning Action to Hide to get the Sneak Attack bonus each round.  The point was brought up that standing on tree branches while wearing boots was a tricky maneuver and would probably require an Acrobatic check to not slip off. Then the pictures were brought out showing talons instead of feet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Owlin have talons.

The description of Owlin in *Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos* does not describe the hands and feet of an Owlin, rather, describes their arms and legs:

> Owlin have arms and legs like other Humanoids, as well as wings that extend from their back and shoulders.

The description emphasizes the general arrangement of limbs, that is, humanoid-like arms and legs, with two additional limbs in the form of wings. Since nothing is said about their hands and feet in official D&D materials, we defer to the DM for a ruling, however, existing art in official publications is a good indicator of the nature of things. As you have observed, the Owlin art typically depicts taloned feet very similar to a real owl. This is the case in the art sprinkled throughout *A Curriculum of Chaos*.

#### The DM decides if a course of action requires an ability check.

To me, it seems quite reasonable for an Owlin to be able to land on a tree branch without issue. If you feel differently, that's okay. The DM gets to decide if a particular course of action calls for an ability check. In this case, I don't see too much of a difference between a rogue Owlin hiding in tree branches and a rogue Human hiding in the bushes or among trees on the ground. If you make it harder for them to do it in a tree, they will just do it on the ground and the outcome will be the same, but it will feel less cool and owl-like.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Markov - that answers my question.

Comment: More like: Owlin have Towlins

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that if they do have foot-talons, they can't use them as natural weapons cast spells, or to wield additional weapons. I imagine the latter two can probably be justified by pointing out the limited dexterity possessed by the talons of birds of prey, where the clenching and opening of the talons is controlled by the degree of extension of the leg.